# Distribute docker image with volume to another machine?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have used this guide to "install" jenkins on my local machine:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

It enables a volume, meaning that each time I run the container my previous changes are still available/persisted (installed plugins, created jobs etc.).

But how do I distribute the image including its state/volume to another machine? Usually I would do a docker commit  on the current state and a save to a tar archive. Next I can move that tar archive to another machine, load the image and run a container.

But how will that work for the above jenkins image with a volume? How do I move the whole thing to another machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data only container pattern](https://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/). It allows you to create another container stored data from volumes from jenkins container. You can save to tar archive both and transfer to another machine.

Also you are free to update, remove jenkins container.

Comment: Ok so what is the benefit of doing this extra work compared to simply just "snapshotting" docker commit the container after each use?

Comment: if you want to update jenkins or change base image you can do it without loosing stored data.

Comment: If I commit the running container its stored as a new image with the data or am I missing your point? At least that's how I have persisted data when working continuously with an image/container